# Android:More efficient solution to fetch images from internet at runtime and show in listview

Tags: android, listview

**Scenario**: A bit tricky but interesting.
I have sent a request that will give me a JSON response. This response will further contain, say 10, JSON request URLs.

I will then send request to these 10 Urls and each URL will then contain 2 image URLs. That means 20 images in total.

My intentions are to show these images in a `ListView` as fast as possible to the user.
This is what I've done till now:

**Step 1:** As soon as the activity starts, pop a `ProgressDialog` showing loading circle as in youtube.

**Step 2:** IN AN `ASYNC TASK`, Send the first request that give URLs of those 10 JSON requests. Send this request then parse & store these 10 URLs present is response.

**Step 3:** Starting from first(out of 10), send the request that will give the JSON response.

**Step 4:** Parse this response to fetch the 2 image URLs and store in LinkedList.

**Step 5:** As we have the actual link of the image now, dismiss the progress dialog and fetch the image.

**Step 6:** This image will be stored in `drawable`. I've made a custom `BaseAdapter` called `ImageAdapter` that has `ArrayList<Drawable> mImages`;

**Step 7:** Store the received drawable in this `ArrayList`, using: `adapter.mImages.add(drawable);`

**Step 8:** Then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` This will update the listview as soon the image is ready to be displayed.

**Step 9:** Back to step 3 to process further URLs.

Below is the code (striped all the unnecessary code):

**ActivityClass**

```
public class ImageViewer extends Activity {
    GridView gvImage;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private final static Integer IMAGE_LIMIT = 10;
    private ImageAdapter adapter;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.ImageViewer);
            gvImage = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvImage);
            adapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
            gvImage.setAdapter(adapter);

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ImageViewer.this, "In Progress",
                    "Loading...", true, true, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
            new SendRequest().execute(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    class SendRequest extends AsyncTask {
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            try {
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(BaseRequest_URL);

                JSONObject jsonResponse = null;

                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet, localContext);
                if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    jsonResponse = getJSONObjectFromEntity(entity); //getJSONObjectFromEntity() will return JSONObject
                    processJSON(jsonResponse);
                }
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return null;
        }

        private void processJSON(JSONObject jsonResponse) throws JSONException {
            for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_LIMIT; i++) {
                // Some JSON parsing. Output will be 'imageURL' which will be image URL
                displayImage(imageURL);
            }
        }

        public void displayImage(String uri150) {
            try {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(uri150).getContent();
                if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "image 150");
                adapter.mImages.add(d);
                handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); // Handler Below
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler(){
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        };
    };
}
```

**ImageAdapter Class:**

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    public ArrayList<Drawable> mImages = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        this.context = c;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        try {
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(mImages.get(position));
            imageView.setTag("Image" + position);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. The way I see it `ImageAdapter` is called several times. Is there any other way to reduce it.
2. How can I optimize the code of ImageAdapter.
3. Any other improvement?

Comment: I recommend using Prime for the image loading half of it. There is an example project on how to use it within a ListView also. https://github.com/DHuckaby/Prime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. (the first 2 questions) Adapter doesn't only control which row (view in the list) appears, it also recycles it. In your Adapter, getView creates a new view every time it is called, when it should only create a new one if the old one is not available. Check out Mark Murphy (commonsware)'s adapter [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials/blob/master/05-FancyList/LunchList/src/apt/tutorial/LunchList.java).
2. In your code, all the images are downloaded during progress dialog. Your user will probably not see them all to the last one and it will definitely burden your memory. I suggest you lazy load both JSON and images (request your JSON, parse it, load the image one-by-one asynchronously depending on how much of the grid your users see/scroll). There have been a lot of discussions regarding image lazy loading and you should definitely start from Fedor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012).

Answer (score 1):

What I can tell you for sure it is **WRONG** to store your images in memory, as you can get **OutOfMemoryException**.

To learn how to work with images and cache visit [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)

Comment: Not caching in memory can cause excessive Bitmap decoding which will more easily result in running out of memory. The best method is to use both a memory and disk cache, as outlined in that nice link you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) library. It is really good for layz loading.

Answer (score 0):

just search for Android LazyImageLoading

Good Luck